# Receive message w/ ptr->char[], update edit control with char array

Tags: c++, winapi

Code below checks to see how many bytes have been received after a EV_RXCHAR event has occurred.

```
// read data here
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
DWORD dwErrors;
COMSTAT cStat;
OVERLAPPED ovRead;
ovRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, true, 0, 0);

ClearCommError(cThis->m_hSerial, &dwErrors, &cStat);
char szBuf[cStat.cbInQue];

bool readState = ReadFile(cThis->m_hSerial, &szBuf, sizeof(szBuf), &dwBytesRead, &ovRead);
if (readState && dwBytesRead == sizeof(szBuf))
        PostMessage(cThis->m_hHwnd, WM_NULL, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(&szBuf), LPARAM(0));
```

the code below receives the msg and passes it on to AppendText() to update the edit control. The problem seems to be that the pointer contains garbage.

```
case WM_NULL:
        {
            TCHAR *pTchar = (TCHAR*)wParam;
            AppendText(hEdit, pTchar);
            break;
        }
```

AppendText() code, which I actually got off this site as an answer to another question.

```
void AppendText(HWND &hwnd, TCHAR * text)
{
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETSEL, length, length);
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(text));

}
```

The question: How do I send a pointer to a char array in PostMessage() as a WPARAM and receive it in the callback as a null terminated string to send to EM_REPLACESEL as a SendMessage()?

**These are the changes I made and it works**

```
// Get the Bytes in queue
ClearCommError(cThis->m_hSerial, &dwErrors, &cStat);
int nSize = cStat.cbInQue;
// EM_REPLACESEL needs a LPARAM null terminated string, make room and set the CString to NULL
char szBuf[nSize+1];
memset(szBuf, 0x00, sizeof(szBuf));

bool readState = ReadFile(cThis->m_hSerial, &szBuf, nSize, &dwBytesRead, &ovRead);
if (readState && dwBytesRead == nSize)
    SendMessage(cThis->m_hHwnd, WM_SERIAL, 0, LPARAM(&szBuf));

case WM_SERIAL:
        AppendText(hEdit, lParam);
        break;

void AppendText(HWND &hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETSEL, length, length);
    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, lParam);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostMessage doesn't block your current thread which leads to a race condition.
That's because you are passing szBuf's reference to PostMessage even though it will be destructed when it's out of scope since it's allocated on the stack.

Is there a specific reason you choose PostMessage over SendMessage?
If not consider using the latter as it will block the thread.

Comment: And if you do need `PostMessage()` you will need to ensure the string buffer remains valid until after the message has been processed. One way to do this would be to dynamically allocate the string in the code that calls `PostMessage()` and then deallocate the string in the message handler. Also if you're dealing with an application-specific message, the block of message numbers starting at `WM_APP` is what you want, not `WM_NULL`. (And `WM_USER` (give or take a few for custom dialog boxes) up to and including `WM_APP - 1` for window class-specific messages.)

Comment: I was still a little bit bugged out with some garbage data even after using `SendMessage()` But I knew `EM_REPLACESEL` need a null terminated string. `memset()` fixed that and now it works and the Serial read speeds are fast.

Also according to the MSDN, `PostMessage()` will fail unless the UINT msg is WM_USER or higher.